# I am trying to have a value subtract 8 only if the value in another cell is greater than 8

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently using the formula below to have a cell say 0 if the numeric value is less than 8.  If the numeric value in that cell is greater than 8, i would like the value to show in the cell and subtract it by 8.

=SUMIF(B3,">8")-8

It works if the value is greater than 8 perfectly, but when it is less than 8 it gives me a negative value, which is what I do not want.  I only want it to subtract 8 if B3 is greater than 8, or show zero if it is not greater than 8.

Comment: Note that you are subtracting 8 *outside the conditional statement*. This is means that you are subtracting 8 from whatever the result of the `sumif()` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use if to set whether you return 0 or the value less 8:

```
=IF(B3<8,0,B3-8)
```

[image]

Or you can use MAX:

```
=MAX(B3-8,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would keep it simple:  `=MAX(0, A1-8)`

When `a1-8` is less than 0, it returns 0  (by definition.)  Otherwise it returns `a1-8`.

For example

```
In Output
-1  0
 8  0
 9  1
10  2
11  3
12  4
13  5
```